# Getting custom HTML attribute with JS and using with "this"

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const allButtonsToStore = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
    let reason = [];
    for (let x=0; x < allButtonsToStore.length; x++) {
      allButtonsToStore[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
        reason[x] = this.textContent;
        console.log("reason" + [x] + ": " + reason[x]);
        reason[x] = this.value;
        console.log("reason" + [x] + ": " + reason[x]);
        reason[x] = this.data-spec;
        console.log("reason" + [x] + ": " + reason[x]);
      });
    }
```

```html
    <div id="gamen" class="hidden">
       <button class='button' data-next="gamen1" data-parent="gamen" data-spec="ram" value="2GB">Lichte games</button>
        <button class='button' data-next="gamen1" data-parent="gamen" data-spec="videokaart" value="2GB">Middel games</button>
        <button class='button' data-next="gamen1" data-parent="gamen" data-spec="processor" value="i9">Zware games</button>
    </div>
```

With JS I'm getting all buttons and, for testing, I'm checking if I can get the attributes (I need the attributes and values later).

`this.textContent;` and `reason[x] = this.value;` are working fine. Only I can't seem to figure out how to get a custom attribute `this.data-spec;`

`this.data-spec;` gives ReferenceError: spec is not defined
`this."data-spec";` and `this."[data-spec]";` gives SyntaxError: Unexpected string

`this.[data-spec];` and `this.(data-spec);` Gives an unexpected token error

Comment: `this.getAttribute("data-spec");`

Comment: @Akshay why did you comment instead of putting it as an answer? I won't be able to reward you with points now

Comment: No worries, the answer below is also helpful, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a HTML5 `data-` attribute, you can actually retrieve its value using [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset), i.e.

```
this.dataset.spec
```

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
const allButtonsToStore = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
let reason = [];
for (let x=0; x < allButtonsToStore.length; x++) {
  allButtonsToStore[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
    reason[x] = this.textContent;
    console.log("reason" + x + ": " + reason[x]);
    reason[x] = this.value;
    console.log("reason" + x + ": " + reason[x]);
    reason[x] = this.dataset.spec;
    console.log("reason" + x + ": " + reason[x]);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="gamen" class="hidden">
   <button class='button' data-next="gamen1" data-parent="gamen" data-spec="ram" value="2GB">Lichte games</button>
    <button class='button' data-next="gamen1" data-parent="gamen" data-spec="videokaart" value="2GB">Middel games</button>
    <button class='button' data-next="gamen1" data-parent="gamen" data-spec="processor" value="i9">Zware games</button>
</div>
```

However, there's something that concerns me in your code, is that you're constantly overwriting `reason[x]`. If you're somehow using the array `reason` later, do note that you will only get the last value (i.e. the value of `data-spec`), and not the `textContent` or the `value` of the element.

---

If you're familiar with using ES6, your code can be further optimized:

```js
const allButtonsToStore = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

allButtonsToStore.forEach((el, i) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(`reason${i}: ${el.textContent}`);
    console.log(`reason${i}: ${el.value}`);
    console.log(`reason${i}: ${el.dataset.spec}`);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="gamen" class="hidden">
   <button class='button' data-next="gamen1" data-parent="gamen" data-spec="ram" value="2GB">Lichte games</button>
    <button class='button' data-next="gamen1" data-parent="gamen" data-spec="videokaart" value="2GB">Middel games</button>
    <button class='button' data-next="gamen1" data-parent="gamen" data-spec="processor" value="i9">Zware games</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I was indeed overwriting because I simply need to know if it's working or not. for future purposes I think I indeed need your improvements. Thank you very much for the extra effort! I need to wait 4 min before I can mark your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method `getAttribute()` for getting the attribute values. you need to use that method and specify the which attribute value you need to get.

For your code it should be like this `this.getAttribute("data-spec");`

If attribute does not exists this will return null or ""